# Are member variables of Hadoop Reducer class thread-safe?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm a newbie of the **Hadoop ecosystem**.

What I want to ask is that: "Are member variables of Reducer class thread-safe?"

1. Mapper passes data to Reducer with unique key.
2. There is a collection(`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`) which is a member variable in Reducer class.
3. The collection is initialized in the `setup(Context)` method of Reducer class.
4. Some `Query` objects(jOOQ) are created and appended into the collection in the `reduce(...)` method of Reducer class.
5. `jooq.batch(collection).execute()` method will be called in the last line of `reduce(...)` method within specified threshold(e.g 1000). And then the collection will be cleared by `clear()` method.
6. The remains of collection from step 4 will be processed as same as step 5 in `cleanup(Context)` method.

***Question***: Do I need to `synchronize` step 5?

### Codes

```
public class SomeReducer extends TableReducer<Text, Text, ImmutableBytesWritable> {
    private Queue<Query> queries;

    @Override
    protected void setup(Context context) {
        ...
        queries = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    }

    @Override
    protected void cleanup(Context context) {
        if (!queries.isEmpty()) db.batch(queries).execute();
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Session> sessions, Context context) {
        for (...iteration...) { queries.add(...create Query object...); }

        // Is this code snippet below should be synchronized?
        if (queries.size() >= 1000) {
            db.batch(queries).execute();
            queries.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Reducer is threadsafe. You will most likely have multiple Reducers running in parallel, but they are completely isolated from each other and only see their own data and instance variables.

So to answer your qustion, you do not need to synchronize your code or even use a ConcurrentLinkedQueue, it could just be a normal ArrayList.